# How can I delete all messages from one hangout chat/room by Hangout Chat API?

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I need to write Hangouts Bot which will delete all messages from the chat/room and after this send new one message. [Hangout API](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/delete) provides a possibility to delete just one message by one request (with a known identifier).

I wrote .sh file with the next code (sending message):

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/SPACE_ID/messages' \
-d '{"text": "Message!"}'
```

How can I delete all messages from the chat before sending a new one? (by Hangouts API)

Comment: Is there any code you have written that we can help you with? Or maybe a specific problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer and added more information. Hope it'll help. Thanks.
P.S it's my first question, sorry)

Comment: @KseniaGolovchik Since it's an http request, maybe something like `/messageID1&messageID2&messageID3...` could work.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the delete method requires a message ID and only deletes one message. There is a [get](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/get) method but it doesn't support returning all messages. If all of the messages you are deleting were generated by the bot itself I would suggest that you keep a running log of the message IDs and use that to delete them. I do not believe a bot can delete a message generated by another user or a bot other than itself just as a user can't delete another user's message.